# Creating multiple sub directories in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, subdirectory

Creating multiple sub directories in unix shell script.

This works manually but through script it does not. And includes the {} braces

ABC.sh
#!/bin/bash
`mkdir -p ~/folder1/folder2/{a,b,c}`

Result:
#`cd folder1/folder2`
#`ls`
#{a,b,c}

Manually without script the folders a,b,c are created under folder 2 as needed:
`mkdir -p ~/folder1/folder2/{a,b,c}`

#`cd folder1/folder2`
#`l`
#a
b
c

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce that behavior if the "braceexpand" option is turned off:

```sh
$ set +o braceexpand
$ mkdir -p folder1/folder2/{a,b,c}
$ find .
.
./folder1
./folder1/folder2
./folder1/folder2/{a,b,c}
```

Since you're relying on it, you could ensure that brace expansion is turned on in your script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -o braceexpand
mkdir -p ~/folder1/folder2/{a,b,c}
```

The [braceexpand option is enabled by default](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html), so something in your environment must be turning it off.

Comment: Your comment seems like it was abbreviated; if this solved the problem, you can indicate that with the checkmark. If there's something still missing, please let me know. Thanks!